# Layout Attributes within Styles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I've been with a dilemma for a while that I don't know how to solve it properly. I want to use **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself), but not apply bad practices in styles (such as set the layout attributes inside them).

This is my case...

To have the text styles encapsulated in my projects, I usually use the following:

I have a style called `Wrap_Content`

```
<style name="WrapContent">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

On the one hand, I have a style called `Tv` that inherits from `WrapContent`:

```
<style name="Tv" parent="WrapContent">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_foo</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_foo</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, apart, the `Tv` style has a default font and text color
If for example I want to use a font size of 15sp, I apply this style:

```
<style name="Tv.15">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

And so on...

Well, the issue is that all the `TextView` of my project I set `wrap_content` both width and height.
Therefore, doing things like this simplifies the layouts XML a lot and it increases the readability and grouping common behaviors.

Example:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/Tv.15"
    android:text="@string/foo"/>
```

And if in any case, I want to change any attribute, I have only to overwrite it from where I call it.

The dilemma is that I am mixing `textAppearance` styles with `layout` ones. I have thought about separating this ... but I have not just resolved the main issue, that I am setting layout attributes on it, something that I should know nothing more than its own view, and not its container.

But what does not convince me at all is to do something like this:

```
<style name="Tv">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_foo</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_foo</item>
</style>

<style name="Tv.15">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<TextView
    style="@style/Tv.15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/foo"/>
```

I don't want to repeat a million times with the same attributes if these are common. Or yes I see what it brings ... **technical debt**. Therefore, it does not seem like a valid option.

I have searched quite a lot and the truth is that I have not found anything that convinces me and I would like to reach something elegant, since it is something that I use at all times and I don't like it.

Well... **what do you think about it?**

Thank you so much!!!

---

**EDITED 2019-11-08**

I have thought a new approach adding a new layer of styles, the `@style/TextAppearance`. It is like this:

```
<style name="WrapContent">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_foo</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_foo</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.15">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Tv" parent="WrapContent">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="Tv.15">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.15</item>
</style>
```

This add a little bit of complexity to the system, but it splits the layout and the textAppearance attributes. Moreover, it allows use the `TextAppearance` style for buttons, editTexts an so on.

Comment: If you had one `textAppearance` style and one `layout` style, you could not apply them to the same `TextView` since each `View` will take only one `style="@style/..."` attribute. So not mixing the two types of attributes seems to be impossible. 
I'm not a design guru but recently I've started to declare styles after the technical role a certain `View` is playing in my app  - labels should have one style throughout the app and headlines another.

Comment: You can apply both things (textAppearance and style) to the same View, @0X0nosugar. Well, just in case it is a TextView. But it is not the issue... :-)

Comment: I meant to say you can't set two style="@style/..." attributes to the same View. So it won't be possible to apply one style which only contains attributes related to layout and one style which only contains attributes related to what it looks like to the same View simultaneously. So trying to separate the two aspects will not work with android even if it may be a good idea from an architecture POV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our most recent Android Dev Summit, two of my colleagues gave a talk on how to use [Theme & Style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owkf8DhAOSo). We advice that you use Themes for View groups and their children and styles for simpler views. Perhaps your layout needs can be met by using Themes and then reserving styles for text appearances and such. Beyond that, efficacy should guide how you structure your style objects.

Comment: Thanks, Isai! I have already seen the video. It is awesome! :-). I have started to apply one of the recommendations they talked about, the `?attr/color`. Regarding styles I have thought other approach adding a new layer of styles. I have edited the answer for showing it ;-)

Comment: What you have is pretty good. A slight note is that since you are using `parent` to extend `WrapContent`, you should considering using the dot notation to make the name of the derivative style more descriptive. Maybe something like "WrapContent.TextAppearance.Tv". So to explain what this means: if you define a `parent` then the system ignores dot notations as just your way of naming your style. Also `TextAppearance` may not be descriptive enough if you have multiple text appearances in your app. (the naming piece makes it easy to remember what's happening at a glance"

Comment: I like it! Thanks, Isai! :-)

Comment: If this answer gave you the directions you needed, please consider accepting it so to help other users/seekers.